# Excel-VBA Copy data from one worksheet to another worksheet and paste in new row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. And below is my code.What i am trying to do is copy data from one worksheet and paste it in another worksheet. The only problem with my code is that every time i try to copy a new file it overwrites the previous data . What i want is to paste data in new line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range
Dim erow
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [Dominoes_Excel!A1]
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox ("No File Specified.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet
End If
    wb2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to start pasting in A1?
Can you add _"Debug Print PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)"_ after 
_"Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)"_ and check if the line moves?

Comment: Thanks but "Debug Print PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)"  still pastes in A1. No I don't want to start pasting in A1. For the first file it would start from A1 but after that it should start from the next line.

Comment: Debug print gives you a result (in the immediate window of VBA) that I would like you to post here to understand if it moves

Answer (score 0):

The next line down is given by

```
Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(1,0)   '1 row down, no columns
```

The next blank line in a sheet (which I suspect is what you want) is given by

```
set pastestart = worksheets("Dominoes_Excel").cells(worksheets("Dominoes_Excel").rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still no luck.